Real-time detection of work item changes in custom Azure DevOps Hub
I'm building an Azure DevOps extension and have created a new custom Hub using azure-devops-extension-api. In this Hub, I display data for a specific work item (e.g., ID: 1001 - Title: Hello World).
I want my Hub to detect changes to this work item in real-time. For example, if I have my Hub open in one window and change the title of the work item from another window (like Backlog or Boards), I'd like my Hub to detect this change immediately (e.g., title changed to Hello World changed).
I've noticed that when I open Boards or Sprints, the console logs messages like:
SignalR: moved from disconnected to connecting /_signalr/
SignalR: moved from connecting to connected for /_signalr/
SignalR: connected!

This suggests that Azure DevOps uses SignalR for real-time notifications, so I’m wondering if there’s a way to use it to detect changes in my custom Hub. However, I haven’t found a clear way to subscribe to these events through azure-devops-extension-api.
Question
Is there a method or API that allows my custom Hub to detect real-time changes to a work item? If not, what would be the recommended approach to achieve this behavior?

Have you tried to listen on onFieldChanged  event?  please check the doc for the details.

Tks I will check it. I did some quick testing and this is triggered when the work-item-form is open. Now I need to figure it out how to connect my Hub. I mean with the registered object. Do you have an example not getting update from the form itself, but from a hub?

Most of the extension samples are listed in link, but i didn't find similar sample which listen from hub.
